# Can't run Cygwin/X as administrator on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, uac

When I run Cygwin/X as administrator, I get periodic errors when I try to run, e.g., xterm.  I can get around this by running as not administrator, but I've been getting these errors when running exim as a service, so I need a better solution.  Is cygwin even set up to run as administrator?  Do I need to do something with UAC to enable this?

The errors I get are:

```
  0 [main] xterm 8352 child_copy: linked dll data write copy failed, 0x2BE000..0x2C27EC, done 0, windows pid 8844, Win32 error 487
xterm: Error 29, errno 11: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

and

```
  0 [main] xterm 5920 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
741 [main] xterm 5920 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to xterm.exe.stackdump
```

The stack dump is not helpful:

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=6102048B
eax=00F300F8 ebx=61246E5C ecx=75530D06 edx=00334118 esi=00000000 edi=0028F9F4
ebp=61020C00 esp=0028C7C4 program=C:\cygwin\bin\xterm.exe, pid 6888, thread main
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
End of stack trace
```

Thanks,

Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  In response to [two](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-status-access-violation) [questions](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-fork-failures) in the FAQ, I reinstalled the basic Cygwin packages, and the problem seems to have disappeared.  As per the instructions in the FAQ, I stopped my Cygwin services and killed all the bash and sh jobs before reinstalling.